# foriegn key constrant fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

what does the below error mean

```
{"info":{"error":{"errorInfo":["23000",1452,"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cs_test_db`.`accountinfo`, CONSTRAINT `fk_accinfo_accttypeid` FOREIGN KEY (`account_type_id`) REFERENCES `accounttype` (`accounttype_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO)"]},"unique_code":""}}
```

Comment: You add a child object with an non existing parent object

Comment: @Jens means here what is the parent object?

Comment: Look into your database and search for the fk fk_accinfo_accttypeid

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are trying to update data in a table that have a constraint of foreign key. Actually, your current table is linked to another table that have a column with data that is the only ones to be present in it.

In order to see the link, please run this command: `SHOW ENGINE IMMODB STATUS;` and search for "**Latest foreign key error**". It will show you the parent table. Or run this other command: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Accountinfo;` to see the foreign key constraint with parent table.

Then, do a select on the parent table and check the data on the column you are using as a constraint... data values present are different from what you are trying to update.